# Generate electric spark with Arduino (high voltage boost converter)

Tags: arduino, boost, high-voltage

Suppose I have an Arduino Uno or a similar board. I would like to have it create an electric spark over a spark gap as reliably as possible when instructed to do so.

As I understand, the minimum voltage required for a spark to form is 3kV per mm of air between the electrodes, so the Arduino has to be able to output a voltage in that order, preferably up to about 10kV in this specific situation. Now, I know that inductors can be used to create something known as a boost converter, which is able to step up the voltage quite a bit:

[image: Boost converter schematic]

*Schematic from Wikipedia (License: Public domain)*

My idea was to connect a digital pin as well as the ground to the "Supply" side, and have the "Load" side be two cables whose ends are spaced a few millimeters apart.

I assume this would fry the board quite quickly. How can I prevent that from happening? Is it even possible to achieve the required output voltage using just the Arduino? If it is, please help with the details for the circuit components I need.

Comment: Perhaps you should research the circuitry used in modern engines where the spark is electronically timed?

Comment: The digital pins of the Arduino (for that fact, any micrprocessor) can't supply enough current to drive a boost circuit to reach the voltage you want.  You would do better to build a circuit that can generate the high voltage, then use the Arduino to turn it on and off.  You need to protect the Arduino from the high voltage discharge, too.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest, safest, most reliable and easy to get going would be to use an auto ignition coil, with a single high voltage N channel FET to switch voltage to it on and off.

It could be isolated more completely from the Arduino using an opto-coupler.